# compilation error due to adding a namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, c++14, initializer-list

I am getting a initializer-list conversion error (static_data.h)
(I use g++ -std=c++14)

```
#include<vector>
#include<string>

namespace Euler2D {

  class static_data{
  public :
    const std::vector<std::string> path{"x","y","z"};
  };

}
```

However I can compile this (and use it without any issue from another class/function)

```
class static_data{
  public :
    const std::vector<std::string> path{"x","y","z"};
  };
```

so How can I put my static_data class into a namespace, without sacrificing initializer-list?

Comment: Works for me: http://ideone.com/QbHVyZ

Comment: @CinCout I am compiling this is a ".h" without a main function

Comment: You still need an entry point, don't you?

Comment: do, I? I just compiled the second case in a .h file and just use the class from another C++ file without an issue. I have seen other large programs use this kind of stand alone, .h files I am not sure what I am missing here

Comment: @CinCout You are right, it does require an entry point, compiling with -c option and then using from a main function works fine. I would like to know why just the pure class version compiles without -c option.

Comment: Works without the -c option: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2f2345a6cc401dda

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111186/discussion-between-fedvasu-and-cincout).

Comment: Can't. Sorry about that. Chat blocked at my end.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using MSVC 2010? In that case you will face problems with initializing vector the way you did.Try this and it should work for you

```
#include<vector> 
#include<string>
using namespace std;

namespace Euler2D {
    class static_data{
      public :    
        static std::vector<std::string> path;
    };
    const char *initialval[] = {"x", "y", "z"};
    std::vector<std::string> static_data::path(initialval, end(initialval)); 
 }
```

Comment: using gcc 5.3. Not MSVC. I will try this solution though

Comment: Ofcourse once u have added a main function , compiler will not complain about an entry point

Comment: Yes it does. But is my path actually const?

Comment: Can you also explain why the OP's method doesn't work?

Comment: I have seen problems in MSVC 2010 with vector initialization. I have not used gcc though but higher version of MSVC doesnt seem to support the initializer lists and hence I would assume its a similar problem

Comment: @fedvasu : perhaps not..compiler would still allow u to change the values of path. But in other case, you would need an instance of the class if u wish to do so in the header file?